# How to import a fixed number of rows in incremental import in sqoop?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, mapreduce, sqoop

I am learning sqoop on my own and tried to locally test the incremental import functionality by using the below mentioned code

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/employees \
--username root \
-P \
--query 'select * from employees WHERE $CONDITIONS ORDER BY emp_no LIMIT 1000' \
-m 1 \
--incremental append \
--check-column emp_no \
--target-dir sqoop/import_data/employee_db_import_incremental
```

The above piece of script imported the first 1000 records and now I want to append the next 1000 records to the existing data. How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the last value, from which record you need to append, suppose your last record is `1000` then your command must be like following:

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/employees \
--username root \
-P \
--query 'select * from employees WHERE $CONDITIONS ORDER BY emp_no LIMIT 2000' 
\
-m 1 \
--incremental append \
--check-column emp_no \
--last-value 1000
--target-dir sqoop/import_data/employee_db_import_incremental
```